# flutter: how to autofill password in login form

Tags: flutter, authentication, passwords

I am trying when user check the checkbox it will autofill the password when user login again, i tried autofillhints in password textfield and wrap the widgets in AutofillGroup, but it is not working, when i login once and login again i am required to enter the password again.

and i am using api for fetching username and password.

here is my login code

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  Login({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  
  final String title;
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var name,password,token;
  bool _passwordVisibilty;

  void initState(){
      _passwordVisibilty=false;
      _formatDateTime();
  }
  String formattedDate;
  String _formatDateTime() {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
    print(formattedDate); 
     
   
  }

  
  //svar localhostUrl="http://10.0.2.2:8000/login";
  var herokuUrl="https://attendance-demo.herokuapp.com/login";

  bool isSameuser = true;
  final String username='';
  final String email='';
  final String designation='';
  Future login() async {
    try{
    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': user.username,
      'password': user.password,
      'date':formattedDate
    };
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrlLogin,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse) async {

//edited code here 
 SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        
        String name=(onResponse.data['User']['username']);
        String password=(onResponse.data['User']['password']);

        if(name==""&&password==""){

          myPrefs.setString('username', name);
          myPrefs.setString('password', password);

        }
        else{
          user.username=name;
          user.password=password;

        }


        
      });}catch(e){
       
        print("error "+e.toString());
       
  

 showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {  
  // Create button  
  Widget okButton = FlatButton(  
    child: Text("OK"),  
    onPressed: () {  
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
    },  
  );  
  
  // Create AlertDialog  
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(  
    title: Text("Error",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
    content: Text("Invalid name or password.",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),),  
    actions: [  
      okButton,  
    ],  
  );  
  
  // show the dialog  
  showDialog(  
    context: context,  
    builder: (BuildContext context) {  
      return alert;  
    },  
  );  
 }
  User user = User('', '');

//--------------------------
  passwordtext(){
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextFormField(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: user.password),
                autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],   //here is used autfodillhints
                onEditingComplete: ()=>TextInput.finishAutofillContext(),  //and i used this too
                decoration: InputDecoration(   
                border: InputBorder.none, 
                 icon: Icon(Icons.lock,color: Colors.blue,),           
                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _passwordVisibilty = !_passwordVisibilty;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                        _passwordVisibilty ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                    ),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText: !_passwordVisibilty,
                   onChanged: (value){
                  user.password=value;
                },
                ),
    );
  }
 
  
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: AutofillGroup(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 155.0,
                  width: 200.0,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/image/company_logo.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),        
                SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                RoundedInputField(
                labelText: "Username",icon: Icons.email,fontsize: textFontSize,
                controller: TextEditingController(text: user.username),
                onChanged: (value){
                  user.username=value;
                }, 
                
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                passwordtext(),
               SizedBox(
                  height: 0.0,
                ),
                Align(

                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child:Row(children: <Widget>[
                   
                      Checkbox(  
                      checkColor: Colors.greenAccent,  
                      activeColor: Colors.blue, 

                      value: isSameuser,  
                      onChanged: (bool newValue) {  
                        if(newValue!=null){
                        setState(() {  
                          isSameuser = newValue;  
                        });  
                      }},   
                    ),
                      Text("Save password?")

                  ],)
                ),
               
                SizedBox(
                  height: 23.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue[500],
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),                             
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(buttonRoundRadius)),
                child: Row(
                  children:<Widget>[                   
                    Expanded(child: 
                    Text("Login",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: textFontSize),),)
                    
                    ,]),
                onPressed: () {   
                login();              
                }               
            )
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use SharedPrefrences.
2. check if username and password is null, if it is null then store the username and password in the preferences.
3. if it is not null set the value of the textController to the values in the sharedPrefrences.

Comment: i edit my code with answer, please check is this you want to say!

Comment: Please invite me to chat.

Comment: how to do this? could u please tell me here